# Defining new tooltips in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I would like to add custom tooltips to emacs.
More specifically, whenever I hover on a symbol (function/variable) name 
with my mouse of I would like to see a tooltip with the symbol's definition.
I know that I can find this kind of info with a tool like cscope but I have no idea how
to attach the output of cscope to a tooltip.
does anyone have a partial (how to link a callback to a tooltip in emacs in general) or 
a full (how do I actually link the output of cscope to a tooltip) solution to this?

Thanks,
Nir

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Emacs installation should include the [Elisp reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html) (if not, download it now - you're going to need it when developing your mode). To access it, go to Info (C-h i) and look for a node labeled "Elisp", sometimes in a separate "Emacs" menu. Type `i` for index and `tooltip` to look for information on tooltips. You should find node [32.19.4 Properties with Special Meanings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#index-help_002decho-_0040r_007b_0028text-property_0029_007d-2589), which tells you that the content of the `help-echo` property is a string that is the tooltip content, or a function that can construct the tooltip dynamically. Explore the manual around that node to find out more about text properties and how to set them.

Here's a simple example:

```
(insert (propertize "foo\n" 'help-echo "Tooltip!"))
```

Type this into your `*scratch*` buffer and press `C-j` to run the code. Then point your mouse at the word "foo" and you should see the tooltip.

Comment: Can you explain the advantages/disadvantages in using text properties instead of overlays?

Answer (score 2):

There is [an AutoOverlay package](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/auto-overlay-manual/html/index.php) that can automatically add overlays, and tooltips associated with those overlays, based on a regex match of the buffer text.