# Emacs: Adding tooltips to output in subsidiary process (in comint, say)

Tags: elisp

I have a process (whose output I can customize) running in a comint shell within emacs, and I want to annotate its output so that it includes tooltips.  As per [Defining new tooltips in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293853/defining-new-tooltips-in-emacs) I might add tooltips to text by using the `echo-help` property.  It looks as if I will have add a filter function to `comint-output-filter-functions` and manually decode the annotated output I will get my sub-process to emit.  Is there a better way?  It seems unfortunate to have to encode information as text in the sub-process, only to have emacs have to decode that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to do something like what you described to get the tooltips.  I'm not sure how else the information would get from the other process to Emacs...

You could set up a socket (in parallel) that communicates the `echo-help` annotations.  But that seems more difficult.